# Single sign-on for two winforms applications

Tags: winforms, database-design, architecture, single-sign-on

There are two different desktop applications, one having oracle as back-end and the other  sql server as back end. Both applications have their own User and User Group Maintenance functionality stored in their respective databases. There is a requirement to create single sign-on ,common User group Maintenance functionality and dashboard. How do we handle the login? For single sign-on, I need to have a user/password that somehow needs to translate to the login information needed for respective applications so that users can access the applications off the dashboard. How do I keep the users in sync between the single sign-on, and the other two applications? Could someone please suggest the best solution/approach for this?
I think one way to go would be to have a different sign-on data database and sync it to both db. But the question is where, oracle or sql server? because a client might have access to only one application or both through single sign-on system.

Comment: The question is too broad. In general It's better to rely on security frameworks. As a simple option, you can perform authentication using asp.net (membership/identity) and then store the authentication cookie/ticket in a common space for those applications. Each application can send that cookie/ticket to the authentication server to make sure if it's logged in.

Comment: In general if the application is not service based and the authentication and authorization is done in application (rather than at service level), then the application is not secure and usually the security can be bypassed by users by cracking the application files.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Is it possible to use cookie or ticket for winform application. If yes where and how do we store it in common place?

Comment: The storage location is up to you. It can be simply a location on file system.